# Telegram Bot deep linking: Is there a maximum payload length of 64 chars?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I am currently trying to send some payload via deep linking, and it seems there is a maximum length limit of 64 chars to be added after the start parameter in the url.

I tried both plaintext and base64 encoding and when I enter more than 64 chars, the listener for /start is not triggered. I am using telegraf js library.

Example link:

https://t.me/EXAMPLE_BOT?start=1233456771121212121212121212121212121212121211111212121212121212

Can anybody else confirm this with their bot? I couldn't find any hints on that in the [deep-linking doc](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking)

Answer (score 1):

Ofc you can't do more than 64 it's standard telegram api limitations